How to get the trigger data as JSON in an Azure Logic App?
I'm trying to do an integration between Dynamics365 and Azure ServiceBus. Basically when records are created/update in D365 I want a message sent to a servicebus.
I have a D365 trigger.
I Have a ServiceBus Send To action.
What I can't figure out is what is the magic words to populate the "Content" property with something like:
{
    "message": ..OriginalTriggeringDataGoesHere..
}

This seems like it should be pretty simple but I can't figure out the template syntax and I can't seem to locate any simple examples that aren't hardcoded JSON blobs.
Halp
Tried lots of variations, but no luck. Latest attempt:
        "actions": {
            "Send_message": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "ContentData": "@{base64ToString(triggerBody())}",
                        "ContentType": "application/json"
                    },


This yields an error: The template language function 'base64ToString' expects its parameter to be a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'
Which is semi-encouraging. At least it's no longer a syntax error... but clearly triggerBody() is not returning a base64 encoded json string.

If the trigger body is null then you have no data. Can you show us an example of the trigger body?

No clue how to egt/see the output of the trigger... so showing an example is a no go.

Can you share the screenshot of your workflow diagram

I believe you are using Microsoft Dataverse connector in your workflow as Dynamic 365 connector has been deprecated.
As per the MSDoc,

The Dynamics 365 connector is officially deprecated and is no longer available. Instead, use the Microsoft Dataverse connector to access Microsoft Dataverse used for Microsoft Dynamics 365 Sales, Microsoft Dynamics 365 Customer Service, Microsoft Dynamics 365 Field Service, Microsoft Dynamics 365 Customer Insights - Journeys, and Microsoft Dynamics 365 Project Service Automation.

In order to send the trigger output body to Service Bus, I have used below workflow-

code-
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Send_message": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "ContentData": "@{base64(triggerBody())}"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('test'))}/messages",
                    "queries": {
                        "systemProperties": "None"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_row_is_added,_modified_or_deleted_(preview)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "entityname": "cra6c_test",
                        "message": 4,
                        "scope": 1,
                        "url": "@{listCallbackUrl()}",
                        "version": 1
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "Consistency": "Strong",
                        "catalog": "all",
                        "category": "all",
                        "organization": "https://*****.crm.dynamics.com"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['commondataservice']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/api/data/v9.1/callbackregistrations"
                },
                "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "commondataservice": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/********/resourceGroups/****/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/commondataservice",
                    "connectionName": "commondataservice",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/*****/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/commondataservice"
                },
                "servicebus": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/*******/resourceGroups/****/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/servicebus",
                    "connectionName": "servicebus",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/******/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/servicebus"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I am able to send the message successfully.
Please ensure, you have data in the trigger body.

